# Finding a path across a grid after randomly filling some proportion of it

Tags: c++, search, pathfinding

Essentially, we must be able to get from one side of the grid to the opposite side of the grid. My code tests for up to down and left to right.

However, this is painfully slow and I'm wondering if there's some way to optimize it. I think the recursion makes sense, and it seems to be working properly based on some of the tests I had outputted. Essentially, I'm finding the proportion of the grid p that needs to be covered in random points to have nearly a 100% chance of there being a path to the other side. A path being defined as moving only left right up or down to get to the opposite side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


const int SIDELENGTH = 2000;
int grid[SIDELENGTH][SIDELENGTH] = {{0}};
int temp[SIDELENGTH][SIDELENGTH] = {{0}};


void copyGrid(bool g2t){
  if (g2t){
    for (int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < SIDELENGTH; j++){
        temp[i][j] = grid[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  else{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < SIDELENGTH; j++){
        grid[i][j] = temp[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
void printGrid(int a [SIDELENGTH][SIDELENGTH]){
  for (int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < SIDELENGTH; j++){
      cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void makeGrid(double prop){
  for (int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < SIDELENGTH; j++){
      if (rand() / double(RAND_MAX) < prop)
      grid[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
}
bool solvePath(int x,int y, bool up){//boolean up is if it's up to down or not if not then it's left to right
//  printGrid(grid);
if (!up){
    if (y == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
    return true;
  }
  if (up){
    if (x == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
    return true;
  }
  if (grid[x][y] == 0 )//ayy c++ doesn't have array index out of bounds lol
  return false;


  grid[x][y] ++;// increment because we already touched this square
  if (x > 0){
    if (grid[x-1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x-1,y,up) )
    return true;
  }
  if (x < SIDELENGTH-1){
    if (grid[x+1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x+1,y,up) )
    return true;
  }
  if (y > 0){
    if (grid[x][y-1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y-1,up))
    return true;
  }
  if (y < SIDELENGTH-1){
    if (grid[x][y+1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y+1,up))
    return true;
  }
return false;

}

bool solve(double startP, double endP, double inc, int trials){


  double numPaths=0, p=startP;
  bool found;
  for (int z = 0; z <(int)((endP-startP)/inc); z++){
    numPaths = 0;
    p+= inc;
    for (int j = 0; j < trials; j++){
      //    printGrid(grid);
      fill(grid[0],grid[0] + SIDELENGTH*SIDELENGTH,0);//reset to 0 grid
      //  printGrid(grid);

      makeGrid(p);
      copyGrid(true);
      //  printGrid(grid);
      for (int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
        found = solvePath(i,0,false);
        if (found){
          numPaths ++;
          break;
        }
      }
      //  printGrid(grid);
      copyGrid(false);//undo increments
      if (!found){//not found so try checking up and down
        for(int i = 0; i < SIDELENGTH; i++){
          found = solvePath(0,i,true);
          if (found){
            numPaths ++;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      /*  printGrid(grid);
      if (found)
      cout << "PATH!" << endl;
      else
      cout << "NOPATH" << endl;
      */
    }
    setprecision(10);
    cout << numPaths << endl;
    cout << trials << endl;
    cout << numPaths/trials << endl;
    cout << "Probability for getting a path with p = " << p << " is " << (double)numPaths/(double)trials << endl;
  }

}
int main(){
  srand(time(0));
  double duration;
  clock_t start;
  start = clock();
  solve(0.58,0.61,0.005,100);
  duration = (clock()-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout << "Total time elapsed: " << duration << " seconds " << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

this little bit of code

> ```
> if (!up){
>     if (y == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
>     return true;
>   }
>   if (up){
>     if (x == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
>     return true;
>   }
>   if (grid[x][y] == 0 )//ayy c++ doesn't have array index out of bounds lol
>   return false;
> ```

is not indented correctly, which makes it hard to read

it should look like this instead

```
if (!up){
    if (y == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
        return true;
}
if (up){
    if (x == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0)
        return true;
}
if (grid[x][y] == 0 )//ayy c++ doesn't have array index out of bounds lol
    return false;
```

personally I think that I would create some variables to hold the boolean conditionals because I think that this piece of your code can be simplified.

```
bool notUpAndSideLengthEqualsY = !up &&  y == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0;
bool upAndSideLengthEqualsX = up && x == SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y] != 0;

if (notUpAndSideLengthEqualsY || upAndSideLengthEqualsX)
    return true;
else if (grid[x][y] == 0)
    return false;
```

Actually, what I would do here is factor out `grid[x][y] == 0` and check that first, because all your statements require `grid[x][y] != 0` do it would look more like this instead

```
bool notUpAndSideLengthEqualsY = !up &&  y == SIDELENGTH-1;
bool upAndSideLengthEqualsX = up && x == SIDELENGTH-1;

if (grid[x][y] == 0)
{
    return false;
} 
else if (notUpAndSideLengthEqualsY || upAndSideLengthEqualsX)
{
    return true;
}
```

There is no need to Check this condition 3 times when once will suffice.

---

Another if statement chain I would simplify is this one

> ```
> if (x > 0){
>     if (grid[x-1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x-1,y,up) )
>     return true;
> }
> if (x < SIDELENGTH-1){
>     if (grid[x+1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x+1,y,up) )
>     return true;
> }
> if (y > 0){
>     if (grid[x][y-1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y-1,up))
>     return true;
> }
> if (y < SIDELENGTH-1){
>     if (grid[x][y+1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y+1,up))
>     return true;
> }
> ```

I would write these differently so that I didn't have to indent. these are all 3 condition if statements that you have made into nested if statements.

```
if (x > 0 && grid[x-1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x-1,y,up)) {
    return true;
}
if (x < SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x+1][y] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x+1,y,up) ) {
    return true;
}
if (y > 0 && grid[x][y-1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y-1,up)) {
    return true;
}
if (y < SIDELENGTH-1 && grid[x][y+1] < grid[x][y] && solvePath(x,y+1,up)) {
    return true;
}
```